# Reversing string and removing duplicate elements in one function

Tags: javascript, string, methods

I'm trying to make a function where whatever the user inputs, the input is reversed with duplicate numbers removed.

Example:
User input = '75845'
Result = '5487'

Here is what I have that reverses the user input.

```
function result(input) {
  var newInput = '';
  for (var i = input.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    newInput += input[i]
  }
  return newInput;
}
```

However, I am not quite sure how to remove duplicate items a user would input as a string. Can I insert some if statement after newInput += input[i] or do I need to rewrite the reverse function as well?

Comment: What about conditionally increasing the loop index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to do a simple duplicate removal. We create an array from the string using [...str], then reverse and use to initialise a Set, then do a join to return a string:

```js
function reverseAndRemoveDuplicates(str) {
    return [...new Set([...str].reverse())].join("")
}

console.log(reverseAndRemoveDuplicates('75845'))
console.log(reverseAndRemoveDuplicates('1233344566'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do the task,

```
function result(input) {
    var res = input.split('').reverse();

    var unique = res
    .filter(function (item, pos, self) {
        return self.indexOf(item) == pos;
    })
    .join("");
    return unique;
}

console.log(result('75845')); // 5487
```